# C# XML delete everything except specific element and its children

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML file:

```
<XtraSerializer version="1.0" application="View">

  <property name="Columns" iskey="true" value="23">
    <property name="Item23" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Name">colworkspace</property>
      <property name="Width">75</property>
      <property name="MinWidth">20</property>
      <property name="MaxWidth">0</property>
    </property>
  </property>

  <property name="FormatRules" iskey="true" value="1">
    <property name="Item1" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="ColumnName">colid</property>
      <property name="Name">Format0</property>
      <property name="RuleType">#FormatConditionRuleExpression</property>
      <property name="Rule" isnull="true" iskey="true">
        <property name="Expression">[id] &gt; 1L</property>
        <property name="Appearance" isnull="true" iskey="true">
          <property name="Options" isnull="true" iskey="true">
            <property name="UseForeColor">true</property>
          </property>
          <property name="ForeColor">195, 214, 155</property>
        </property>
      </property>
    </property>
  </property>

</XtraSerializer>
```

It has two properties, `Columns` and `FormatRules`. I want to delete the  `Columns` property and keep the  `FormatRules` property. What I have done is creating a method that deletes all elements which does not have `name` = `FormatRules` but that will delete all the children of the `FormatRules` property too, which I don't want. This is my code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
IEnumerable<XElement> element = from node in doc.Descendants("property")
                                let attr = node.Attribute("name")
                                where attr != null && attr.Value != "FormatRules"
                                select node;
element.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
doc.Save(path);
```

This will result in this XML file:

```
<XtraSerializer version="1.0" application="View">         
  <property name="FormatRules" iskey="true" value="1">       
</XtraSerializer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//IEnumerable<XElement> element = from node in doc.Descendants("property")
  IEnumerable<XElement> element = from node in doc.Root.Elements("property")
```

Comment: OK, `doc.Root` then.